# Alternatives for Execution Plan viewer in SQL Server 2008R2 or 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I need to enhance query performance and analyze queries but I am unable to open/see Execution Plan viewer. This is because "SHOWPLAN Permission" is denied in my environment (probably because it stresses the CPU). Anyways, are there alternatives to Execution Plan viewer? Could I get similar types of information via other means?

Also, with or without Execution Plan viewer, does anyone know how to open the Seek Predicates window? (I can't upload picture because apparently I don't have good enough reputation lol)

Thanks so much!

Comment: anything that analyses query execution is going to add an overhead and potentially slow performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try executing "SET STATISTICS IO ON;" before you run your query.

In the "Messages" pane, it will tell you how many logical page reads (8K each) it is doing on each table.  Not the only metric to look at, but very useful nonetheless, for identifying what is slowing down your queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I will try that. Also, do you know how to open the Seek Predicates window? I don't know where it is.

Comment: Sorry, I've never heard of that.  SET STATISTICS will work really well.  Good luck.

Comment: I can't even vote on these answers because of my "reputation". This site is unusually strict ...

Answer (score 0):

I just created a user x with read only permission, logged in as x and was able to do the following:

```
set showplan_text on
```

select * from sys.objects

Try and you may find what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was rejected for the same reason as my attempt at seeing it visually! It works though if you have proper permissions.